# Save Date to base | format date in Date Picker of Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I want to save date to my base like this format: "29 September 1983", but I get: "Thu Jun 28 2018 14:44:33 GMT+0300". What I do wrong?

```
const dateFormat = "D MMMM YYYY";

class Create extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date_created: moment()
    };

    this.handleDateCreatedChange = this.handleDateCreatedChange.bind(this);
  }

    fetch("http://localhost:8000/invoices", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        date_created: this.state.date_created
      })
    })
  }

  handleDateCreatedChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.setState({ date_created: event.toString() });
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <DatePicker style={{ width: 630 }}
                   value={moment(this.state.date_created, dateFormat)}
                   format={dateFormat}
                   onChange={this.handleDateCreatedChange}
       />
```

.....etc

Comment: Please make sure code you add here is formatted in a readable way, e.g. uniform indentation. Also, what do you mean by "base"? Database?

Comment: I mean json-server

Comment: @OkK did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to format value as:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/invoices", 
    {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {date_created: this.state.date_created.format('D MMMM YYYY')} // format date here
        )
    }
)

handleDateCreatedChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    // No need to format
}

render() {
    ...
    <DatePicker 
        ...
        value={this.state.date_created}
        ...
    />
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I get an error: "Error: The value/defaultValue of DatePicker or MonthPicker must be a moment object after `antd@2.0`, see: https://u.ant.design/date-picker-value"

Comment: thanks a lot! I added .format('D MMMM YYYY') in fetch as you say